# How to typeset entropy function H?

Tags: symbols

What's the right way to write Shannon's entropy, which is represented as H(...)?  `$H(...)$` will render it in italic *H*, while [Wikipedia seems to render it in normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) H(...) instead.

Which one is more right? And if Wiki is the right one, then how to write it so in math mode?

Comment: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/writinghelp/latex/latex-intro-screen.pdf

Comment: http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/phfqit/phfqit.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asking which typographical conventions are "more right" than others is not likely to generate unanimous consent.

Here are eight ways to generate the Latin-alphabet letter "upright-H" in math mode, for various choices of font shape, weight, and family. Choose your favorite -- and be sure to alert your readers as to which typographic choice you make regarding the symbol for Shannon's entropy.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}  % for \mathfrak and \mathbb
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % for \mathscr
\begin{document}
$H$ $\mathrm{H}$ $\mathbf{H}$ $\mathsf{H}$ 
$\mathcal{H}$ $\mathfrak{H}$ $\mathscr{H}$ $\mathbb{H}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

My it is only a suggestion to typeset entropy measures, including the Shannon or von Neumann entropy included in the package `phfqit`: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/phfqit/phfqit.pdf

The symbol it is just that of the @Mico's answer: the first `H`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{phfqit}
\begin{document}
$\Hmaxf[\rho][\epsilon]{X}[Y]$
\[\Hmaxf[\rho][\epsilon]{X}[Y]\]
\end{document}
```

[image]